How to automate refresh of an Excel sheet which has Rand() function in it on daily basis within excel. Without using python
I have a sheet on excel which has to be refreshed daily without using python or other applications. It has Rand() function in it. So I have to generate new data every day.
I haven't tried anything till now. I know it can be solved using python. But I want to do within excel.

RAND() refreshes every time the sheet is updated, unless you have that turned off using VBA? Might look into that.

Unless you never close your workbook, the RAND() function will generate a different value each time the workbook is opened. It will also recalculate whenever the worksheet is changed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
